# Dynamically add different sized data sets to Google Visulation Chart

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, xml, google-visualization

I loop through data using simpleXML. I'm looking for a flexible way to loop through the data for purposes of drawing a Google Chart. Keeping in mind that the number of columns for the Google Chart will vary at any stage.

Below is a sample of the data I am trying to plot on the chart.

```
<dealers>
  <dealer>
    <dealer>Sydney</dealer>
    <sales>265</sales>
    <year>2015 FY</year>
  </dealer>
  <dealer>
    <dealer>Sydney</dealer>
    <sales>218</sales>
    <year>2016 FY</year>
  </dealer>
  <dealer>
    <dealer>Melbourne</dealer>
    <sales>143</sales>
    <year>2016 FY</year>
  </dealer>
  <dealer>
    <dealer>Brisbane</dealer>
    <sales>181</sales>
    <year>2016 FY</year>
  </dealer>
</dealers>
```

How can I loop through it to produce the below to draw the chart?

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['Year', 'Sydney', 'Melbourne', 'Brisbane'],
                  ['2015 FY', 265, 0, 0],
                  ['2016 FY', 218, 143, 181]
                ]);
```

Remembering that in the future we may have a new dealer and hence the loop would need to be flexible enough to add the new dealer as a column, and correspondingly the values in the correct position in the rows. Also as shown in sample data above, it would need to add a 0 to the row is no value was specified for that year.

Comment: Going to need more info, like, how are you going to get the xml to the client? Does the xml have a namespace? Have you built the page yet, anymore code you can share?

Comment: @WhiteHat I have no problem fetching the XML and looping through it to access the data within the XML, the part I am struggling with is figuring out a logical way to put it into the format of the array above to work with the chart.

Example code of how I get the XML is:

$requestURL = 'http:/example.com/API.php?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2';

$xmlString = simplexml_load_file($requestURL);

foreach ($xmlString->dealer as $dealer ) {

echo $dealer ->dealer;
echo $dealer ->sales;
echo $dealer ->year;

}

Comment: Good to hear, I have the perfect example, when I get to work in the morning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the function I use to build the array for `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable`. It needs a two-dimensional array, you can use intrinsic values or literal objects for each column heading/value.

The first section builds the column headings. With the object, you can assign values for `id`, `label`, and `type`. [maybe others...](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#arraytodatatable)

For the column values, the object has two keys: `v` (value) and `f` (formatted value).

```
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(GetXmlDataArray(xmlObj), false);

  function GetXmlDataArray(sender, args) {
    var colArray;  // column heading array
    var colHdr;    // column heading
    var colValue;  // column value
    var gglArray;  // array to be returned
    var rowArray;  // data row array
    var nlItems;   // xml columns
    var nlRows;    // xml rows

    // init return array and column heading array
    gglArray = [];
    colArray = [];

    // get columns heading xml nodes
    nlItems = sender.get_xml().selectNodes('//cog:item');

    // build column headings
    for (var i = 0; i < nlItems.length; i++) {
      // column literal
      colHdr = {};
      colHdr.id = 'column_' + i;
      colHdr.label = nlItems[i].getAttribute('name');

      // check data type
      switch(nlItems[i].getAttribute('type')) {
        case 'xs:double':
          colHdr.type = 'number';
          break;

        case 'xs:dateTime':
          colHdr.type = 'datetime';
          break;

        default:
          colHdr.type = 'string';
      }

      // add column
      colArray.push(colHdr);
    }

    // add column headings to return array
    gglArray.push(colArray);

    // get column value xml nodes
    nlRows = sender.get_xml().selectNodes('//cog:row');

    // build data rows
    for (var i = 0; i < nlRows.length; i++) {
      // init row array
      rowArray = [];

      // process each column
      for (var x = 0; x < nlRows[i].childNodes.length; x++) {
        // check if column is null
        if (nlRows[i].childNodes[x].getAttribute('xs:nil')) {
          colValue = null;
        } else {
          // set the text value, depends on the browser
          colValue = nlRows[i].childNodes[x].text || nlRows[i].childNodes[x].textContent;
        }

        // check the data type
        switch(colArray[x].type) {
          // format date columns
          case 'datetime':
            // ensure there is a value
            if (colValue) {
              // set date value
              colValue = new Date(colValue);

              // add column value to row array
              rowArray.push({
                v: colValue,                  // column value
                f: colValue.toLocaleString()  // column formatted value
              });
            } else {
              rowArray.push(colValue);
            }
            break;

          default:
            // add column value to row array, no object needed
            rowArray.push(colValue);
        }
      }

      // add column values to return array
      gglArray.push(rowArray);
    }

    return gglArray;
  }
```

The XML I'm using looks similar to this...

```
<dataset>
    <metadata>
          <item name="Site" type="xs:string" length="18"/>
          <item name="ID" type="xs:double" precision="2"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value>ABC</value>
            <value>4886</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>DEF</value>
            <value>4667</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>GHI</value>
            <value>2892</value>
        </row>
        ...
    </data>
</dataset>
```

Comment: Thanks a million for that! I was able to adapt it to work out a solution to my problem!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!